# vlc won't use nautilus when trying to open a file

Tags: gnome, nautilus, vlc

I'm using ubuntu 19.10 with gnome desktop.
I have installed vlc 3.0.10 using snap.

vlc is working well unless when I try to open a file from inside the app (not using "open with" option in nautilus). but when I choose open file from top menu, vlc uses a old-style explorer to navigate and choose the file instead of nautilus. the explorer is shown in the screenshot bellow.

[image]

my question is how can I get vlc to use nautilus as file explorer?

Comment: Not sure why you expect it to use Nautilus. This is the way VLC is supposed to work.

Comment: Welcome! Not exactly a solution, but installing it using `apt` uses nautilus, at least in 20.04.